# After 13.10 update bluetooth will not turn on

Tags: 13.10, bluetooth

Just as the title states my bluetooth worked fine until the 13.10 update. It will not turn on at all. My bluetooth keyboard with a separate adapter works though. Wifi works as well. I don't really expect a response but since I can't seem to get it to send an error report I'm reporting it like this.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. I was too facing a similar problem. My blue-tooth was on when I first started Saucy Salamander but once I disabled it I can neither use it in my Windows nor in Ubuntu.
I got it fine by

```
sudo rfkill unblock bluetooth
```

and you will need this command every time you disable it.

Comment: Could you explain the root of the problem? btw your solution works for me

Comment: there are two ways to turn off a wireless device in Ubuntu:
1.hard block
2.soft block
normally when we turn off any device in windows it is a soft block and can be turned on easily via GUI.
but when we turn off a wireless device in Ubuntu we do it as a hard block and the way to turn it on is this.